# Pattern for Python Redis Pub-Sub-multithreading? Async?

Tags: python, asynchronous, publish-subscribe

I have a function being triggered by a Redis pubsub message. The problem is that this function, which loads a video and streams it to Redis frame by frame, is blocking, and therefore subsequent messages do not get through.

What is the simplest and most effective pattern to solve this class of problems?

The subscription:

```
conn = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port="6379")
if not conn.ping():
        raise Exception('Redis unavailable')

pubsub = conn.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe("feed")
data = None
for message in pubsub.listen():
    logging.info("received pubsub message")
    logging.info(message)
    logging.info(message['type'])
    if message['type'] == "message":
        data = json.loads(message.get("data"))
        if data and data['source']:
            try:
                args.infile = data['source']
                loader = Video(infile=data.get("source"), fps=30.0)
                load(loader, conn, args)
            except error:
                logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
```

The Video class:

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self, infile=0, fps=30.0):
        try: 
            self.isFile = not str(infile).isdecimal()
            print('video: self.isFile', self.isFile)
            self.ts = time.time()
            self.infile = infile
            self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(self.infile)
            if not self.isFile:
                self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
                self.fps = fps
                # TODO: some cameras don't respect the fps directive
                self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
                self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
            else:
                self.fps = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
                self.sma = SimpleMovingAverage(value=0.1, count=19)
        except error as error:
            # Output expected AssertionErrors.
            logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
 
    def __iter__(self):
        self.count = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            self.count += 1
            if not self.fps:
                self.fps = 30.0
            # Respect FPS for files
            if self.isFile:
                delta = time.time() - self.ts
                self.sma.add(delta)
                time.sleep(max(0,(1 - self.sma.current*self.fps)/self.fps))
                self.ts = time.time()

            # Read image
            ret_val, img0 = self.cam.read()
            if not ret_val and self.isFile:
                self.cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                ret_val, img0 = self.cam.read()
            assert ret_val, 'Video Error'

            # Preprocess
            img = img0
            if not self.isFile:
                img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

            return self.count, img
        except AssertionError as error:
            # Output expected AssertionErrors.
            redisLog("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
        except Exception as exception:
            # Output unexpected Exceptions.
            logging.exception("Exception occurred")

    def __len__(self):
        return 0
```

The load function:

```
def load(loader, conn, args):
    try:
        for (count, img) in loader:
            _, data = cv2.imencode(args.fmt, img)
            msg = {
                'count': count,
                'image': data.tobytes()
            }
            _id = conn.xadd(args.output, msg, maxlen=args.maxlen)
            if args.verbose:
                print('frame: {} id: {}'.format(count, _id))
            if args.count is not None and count+1 == args.count:
                print('Stopping after {} frames.'.format(count))
                break
    except AssertionError:
        logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Multiprocessing. This was a bit of a pain, since you can only pass Pickelable arguments to a child process, which means that connections are out. I therefore had to connect from within the child process.

```
procs = []
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

for message in pubsub.listen():
    logging.info("received pubsub message")
    logging.info(message)
    logging.info(message['type'])
    try:
        if message['type'] == "message":
            data = json.loads(message.get("data"))
            if data and data['source']:
                    for proc in procs:
                        if proc.is_alive():
                            proc.terminate()
                            proc.join(timeout=0)
                            procs.pop(0)
                    loaderProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=load, args = (data.get("source"), args,))
                    procs.append(loaderProcess)
                    loaderProcess.start()
                    continue
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
```

...

```
def load(source, args):
    try:
        conn = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port="6379")
        if not conn.ping():
            raise Exception('Redis unavailable')

        loader = Video(infile=source, fps=30.0)
        for (count, img) in loader:
            _, data = cv2.imencode(args.fmt, img)
            msg = {
                'count': count,
                'image': data.tobytes()
            }
            _id = conn.xadd(args.output, msg, maxlen=args.maxlen)
            if args.verbose:
                print('frame: {} id: {}'.format(count, _id))
            if args.count is not None and count+1 == args.count:
                print('Stopping after {} frames.'.format(count))
                break
    except AssertionError:
        logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
        raise
```